# Как определить шрифт?

Tags: css

Помогите определить шрифт? в дизайне Roboto, но почему-то он не похож на шрифт как по дизайну, буквы в дизайне более вытянутые и сжатые

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

https://jsfiddle.net/srzL3ymu/6/

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500;700;900&display=swap");

div {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 56px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #1b1e6f;
}
```

```html
<div>
До окончания акции осталось:
</div>
```

Comment: Сжатые — значит Roboto Condensed, наверное?

Comment: спасибо, не слышал о таком шрифте)